# I want to change my user name

Tags: users, username

Is it possible to change my user name? It was only after choosing it that I realised I had misspelled it.

Answer (score 2):

How friendly are you with databases? The simpliest way is to change it in database directly. You need to check table WP_users and WP_users meta. Everything else is according to ID of that user and gravatar is checking your email so there is no problem in changeing it in database.

Unfortunately you can't do it in wordpress from admin panel. It is restricted.

Hope it helps.

Comment: We just have to be careful about username duplication when modifying the database directly, specially for large number of users.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on what type of user role you have in WordPress: Admin, Editor, Forum Participant, Customer, etc. If you have any role other than Admin, there's not a lot you can do, without the help of someone with Admin rights.

If you *are* an admin, there are plugins that can accomplish this. But, it may be just as easy to create a second user and migrate to that, especially if it's a new blog or you don't have much content associated with your account.

**Migrate to a New User:**

1. Change the email address associated with the misspelled user. WordPress requires a unique email address for each user. If you have a second valid email, this is best. But you can also use a fake one, as long as you don't accidentally lock yourself out of your account.
2. Create a new user with the correct spelling and your original email address.
3. If you've created any posts with the misspelled user, you should re-assign those posts to your new user. Here's a tutorial: [The Easy Way of Changing the Author of Multiple Posts in WordPress](http://starrguide.com/change-author-multiple-posts-wordpress/)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in many ways. A simple way create a new account with right name. Delete the previous id but transfer all contents to the new id.